# Is there an applet equivalent of android's bitmap factory?

Tags: java, android, applet, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have an android project, and I'm porting some of the project into an Applet based spin off. Is there a similar image manipulation library for android's BitmapFactory that I can use in the applet? I need to specifically load and scale JPEGs and convert them to bitmaps for use as JOGL textures. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.